# How to Publish a Web API .NET Core 3.0 app to multiple servers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API with .NET core 3.0 and I want to publish it to 10 servers (with Windows server) at the same time. Which tool can I use to do that?

Comment: There are a *lot* of ways to do that. Starting from running multiple `dotnet publish` commands, to using Windows Server's own `Powershell DSC, to creating CI/CD pipelines using eg Puppet or Azure DevOps

Comment: The [Create a website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/quickstarts/website-quickstart?view=powershell-7) DSC example shows how you can deploy a web site and copy files from a source directly to the target servers. You can target multiple servers by adding nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has multiple answers, I will try to explain the concepts and then the decision is yours.

#### The publish command

[dotnet publish - IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli) - You can use this to create the deployment package, that is the folder that needs to be put on IIS (if that's your deployment server)

[dotnet publish - NGinx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - Another guide on how to deploy on linux server.

You can use the above guides to do the manual copy. You can create a bash or powershell script to copy on the target folders simultaneously.

#### Using a CI/CD pipeline

If you are using azure Devops, you can create a build and release pipeline. [Check the guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops)

[Check another guide here on Azure DevOps](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/)

There are other tools available for CD, like Jenkins, GitLab (the list goes on).